# Sql If/When, Case/When

Tags: sql

I want to write a SQL for when Company = A, use price for Company B.

How can I do this?

Can I use a CASE WHEN Statement for this?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Provide your SQL and more detail if you can, please.

Comment: You can use If's and you can use case statements, however these can drastically reduce performance depending on the dataset, but if you provide examples of what you have tried it would make it easier to help.

Comment: Please show example of your table structure and state the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not contain enough information to be answered.  It requires the RDMS tag along with a description of the table structure.

Comment: There is no `if` in (standard) SQL.

Comment: So, this is what I am trying to do: 1. I have Company A & Company B, the cost price for Company B is what I want to auto-populate in my report, even if the Company is A and quantity is for Company A.  I don't have a SQL yet, since I don't know where to begin. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN [COLUMNCOMPANY] = 'A' THEN [COMPANY_B_PRICE] ELSE [NORMALPRICE] END AS COMPANYPRICE
from [TABLENAME]
```